# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

Tags: android

I am trying to use DateTimeFormatter to format date and time. Using below code

`DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
dateFormat.format(LocalDateTime.now());`

But it throws NoClassDefFoundError.

My gradle file having below configuration:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

I am not getting what is wrong here.

Comment: DateTimeFormatter was added in API level 26, you have min 16.

Comment: So, is there any trick to use it with min sdk 16, because it has been included in java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you get that, it means the class doesn't exists.

Use **RelativeDateTimeFormatter** instead